# Proper Form Input Sanitation

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter, sanitization

I have form fields i'm gathering from my form using

```
 var dataString = $("form").serialize();
```

I am then sending this over to my controller as dataType "html"

The var_dump for my dataString looks like this (so far, but it will contain email address, select options, etc)

```
array(3) {
  ["username"]=>
  string(5) "mikey"
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(4) "tes%"
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(6) "tester" }
```

my question is as follows: What is the proper method of form sanitation i should be using before I send data to my model? I know I need to strip special characters and the like, is there some prepackaged class I should be using?

Do I need to break my data up like

```
  $username =  trim(Array[0]) ;
```

Comment: Your question title is about validation, but the body talks about sanitisation. Which is it? Are you looking to sanitise and/or validate the inputs before they leave the client or once they hit your view, but before the model?

Comment: @melBoyce sorry it's about sanitation got a little confused myself.

Comment: "I know I need to strip special characters" --- for what? Try to input any "special" character here on SO - do they strip anything?

Comment: Has either answer below solved your issue? If so, please mark one as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable XSS Filtering on `application/config/config.php`

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter's [`xss_clean`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/security_helper.html) function should be sufficient for most purposes.

Edit: Thanks to @Starx's answer for pointing out that you can have this function be called for you automatically by setting `$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;` in your `config.php` file.

Also check out the Form Validation class. Here's an example:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#preppingdata

Also, since you're sending the form data via AJAX I just wanted to mention that doing input sanitization in Javascript is fairly useless since it's possible to bypass it, so doing it on the server-side, as it seems you were planning to do anyway, is definitely the way to go.